# Create file with date and time stamp in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, timestamp

I would like to create a file whose name is the current time.
i've tried this code below but it's not working :

```
$Currentpath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$FileLogdate = Get-Date -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
Write-Host($FileLogdate) 

New-Item -Path $Currentpath -Name "$FileLogdate" -ItemType "file"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surround your `Get-Date` with parentheses, like so:

```
(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss)
```

So:

```
$Currentpath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$FileLogdate = (Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss)
Write-Host($FileLogdate) 
# Outputs: 2019-02-25_08-02-25

New-Item -Path $Currentpath -Name "$FileLogdate" -ItemType "file"
```

Comment: @Stuart Not only is your answer wrong, i.e. the parenthesis have nothing to do with his issue, but you have changed the format of the timestamp. Incidentally, that is what fixed the problem.

Comment: @Florian You're right. I missed the point there and didn't explain what i was thinking at all, it's a confusing answer.

Answer (score 6):

As has been mentioned already, the issue is the special chars that aren't allowed in filenames.

I would also use a different format of your date, reverse the date format so that it starts with year:

```
Get-Date –format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'
```

This way  if there are more than one file named this way, they will sort nicely in chronological order in a folder view

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a file with `/` or `:` in its name, you should parse the name you created in `$FileLogdate` and replace the `/` and `:` with `.` or `_`

For example try to change your 2nd line to this:

```
$FileLogdate = Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH_mm_ss'
```

Comment: I've tried this :
    $FileLogdate = Get-Date -format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'

But still have an error :

Comment: yes, the ":" are also a problem, I've updated my answer